# Issues with ODBC Drivers formatting date fields incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc, driver, sqldatatypes

I have been having problems with using mulitple ODBC connections with different drivers to linked tables. When I use the ODBC driver 'SQL Native Client 10.0' the dates format correctly (For Example, US Layout, **02/15/2013**) and within the tables and the dates have a data type of Date/Time.

But when I change the ODBC to an identical connection, but change the driver to SQL Server I notice that within all the linked tables, the data types for Date/Time are changes to Text and the date appears like so - **2013-02-15 00:00:00.0000000**.

I need the SQL Server driver to hold the Date/Time data types.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue after wrecking my brains.

The sql server was setup to hold the dates as datetime(2). This was changed to datetime and it solved the issue.